# How do I apply syntax highlighting to a string literal in Code Mirror?

Tags: jupyter-lab, codemirror

I'm writing a python library that operates on C++ code stored in string literals.  The normal use case is to create a `code` object like so:

```py
code(r"""
void* foo() {
   return NULL;
}
""")
```

The library is meant to work in Jupyter Lab which uses Code Mirror for syntax highlighting/editing, so I'd like to extend Code Mirror to identify calls to `code()` and apply C++ syntax highlighting to its argument, so it'd look something like this:

```py
code(r""" # python highlighting
```

```cpp
void* foo() {  // C++ higlighting
   return NULL;
}
```

```py
""")
```

I know how to do something similar in Pygments, but I'm not sure where to get started with Code Mirror.